# Laravel 5.3 validation to check whether a input value is same as given value in rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using a date range and total number of days between that as another field. I wish to validate the number of days field with the duration between the date range using Laravel 5.3 validation.
For example,
If i give

```
$request->input('start_date') ="2016-12-28";
$request->input('end_date') = "2016-12-30";
$request->input('total_days') = "2";
```

Then there should be an error saying that "the total number of days mismatch with the duration"

Please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Extending Validator

You can create a custom validation rule for this as below. Extend validator and add your custom rule.

```
Validator::extend('sameDuration', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $parameters[0]);
        $endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $parameters[1]);
        $length = $endDate->diffInDays($startDate);
        return $length == $value;
});
```

You should register this in your AppServiceProvider's boot method.

#### Using Custom Rule

You can use it like below in your controller.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'total_days' => 'sameDuration:' . $request->get('start_date') . ',' . $request->get('end_date')
]);
```

#### Adding Error Message

You can add your validation failure error message in your validation language file(Located in resources/lang/en/validation.php). Make sure to add it to first level of the array.

```
'sameDuration' => 'Total number of days doesn't match the chosen date range.'
```